# Cannot enable confetti on path

Tags: opportunity, administration, salespath

Tried with 2 of my trailhead playgrounds and the option is grayed out

[image]

Object: Opportunity
Field: Stage

I confirmed I have stage values on a Closed/Won category.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to:

1. **Enable Path** for your org. From `Setup`, enter `Path Settings` in the Quick Find box.
   Click **Enable**. To let users decide whether the path remembers its previous state, select **Remember User's Path Preferences**. If not selected, the path’s details are hidden when the page that the path is on loads. To **Enable Path** user should have **Modify All Data** or **Customize Application** permission.
2. Add the **View Setup and Configuration** permission to the profile, if that's permissible.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up fixing it by modifying the HTML of the setup page and manually enabling the checkbox :) no idea why it was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Not very intuitive - It seems it's disabled until you set Activate Your Path to true:

[image: Confetti]